# MaterializeCSS - Change when fixed sidenav will be shown automatically

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a pretty normal sidenav:

```
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

<ul class="side-nav fixed" id="slide-out">
...
</ul>
```

But I want it to only appear automatically without clicking on the menu item when the screen is extra large.

How can I change this setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries.

Here is a sample:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  .side-nav .fixed{
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

This will make your navigation visible when your document width is 1024px or more. You can change the pixels to your needs.

See [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kswjfv4f/)

Since the navbar is fixed you will need to change it's `position` value or offset your page content by the navigations width.